# How to plot result of OMNeT++ in real time

Tags: omnet++

I want to animate result with simulation in OMNeT++. Can anybody help me? Is there any way I can use Matplotlib?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what do you mean by 'plot in real-time' and 'animate'? A lot of statistical variables are written out at the end of the simulation so obviously you cannot show them during the simulation run.

It is possible to show real-time inspectors in Qtenv if you augment your source code by hand with the proper statistics. See the `histograms` example in the `samples`.

If you want to use Matplotlib (for post-processing) I recommend to use OMNeT++ 6.0 (preview) as it comes with a new result analysis module which is based on numpy and matplotlib.